# Typescript sharing custom methods on primitive types across project

Tags: javascript, java, typescript

I am trying to implement a Binary Search Tree ([Github repo](https://github.com/ghoshabhi/BinarySearchTree-TS)).

For operations like `insert(data: T)`, `find(data: T)` and `remove(data: T)`, I saw some examples in Java that have the following signature:

**`class BST<T extends Comparable<? super T>> { ... }`**

I believe with this signature it lets us create a BST comprising of objects too as a **`Node`**. Something like this:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
  ///...
  ///..
  @override
  int compareTo(Person otherObj) {
    // return 0 | -1 | 1;
  }
}
```

I'd like to implement something similar through generics in TypeScript. Here are the problems I faced and need help with/suggestions for:

1. Unlike Java, JS primitive types don't have the `compareTo` method - hence my question - How to add methods to primitive types and share that definition across the whole project. Something with creating a **`namespace`**?

> ```
> interface Number {
>   compareTo(o: number): number;
> }
>
> Number.prototype.compareTo = function(o: number) {
>   // add checks for corner cases
>   return this > o ? 1 : this < o ? -1 : o;
> }
>
> let a = 2;
> let b = 3;
> a.compareTo(b); // -1;
> ```

My first question is how to share this new prototype method throughout the project?

2. **Alternatives** Can someone please suggest some alternative which in a way builds a generic binary search tree for all types of data.

**`class BST <T | T extends Comparable<T>> implements Tree<T> {...}`**

But this gave me compilation error saying that `Comparable is being used as a value when it is only a _type_` among other syntax errors.

My idea was: the **`T`** should either be a primitive type or it should of the type that is implements the **`Comparable<T>`** interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That declaration should have worked unless the containing file was an ES6 module, in which case you'd have to put `declare global { ... }` around the interface declaration.  If it didn't work, what error are you getting?
2. The best thing might be to just have the constructor of `BST` take a comparator of type `(x: T, y: T) => number`.  Then callers can use a primitive type with a comparator other than the standard ordering if they want to.

Comment: Thank you Matt. I hadn’t put the “declare global”. The constructor approach should work too. Will try out both and let you know :) thanks again!

Comment: Matt: I get the following error when I simply add `declare global` in the file: **`[ts] Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.`**. Should the file name or it's location matter at all?

Comment: Sorry I think I wrote it wrongly, this worked: **`declare interface Number { compareTo(numObj: Number): -1 | 0 | 1;`**

Comment: I am fairly new to Typescript, is there a convention we need to follow in case of declaring such globals?

Comment: Not that I know of; I still don't know why the previous thing you tried didn't work.  Though whenever you extend globals, there is always some risk of conflicts if other code tries to extend globals, which the constructor approach would avoid.

Comment: The code snippet which I tried worked for one file. I wanted to share that across other files too for which I needed the `declare global`. I am facing another problem now. And that is that I have declared the `compareTo` method on object types (`Number` and `String`) but not on primitive types: `number`, `string`.

Comment: Also, the **`declare interface Number { ... }`** is not working. When I go to some other file, I do get the new `compareTo` method in VSCode's intellisense, but when I run the file I get an error. I am using the `ts-node` package to run my code. I also changed the file name to `globals.d.ts` but then I couldn't add my definition for the new prototype method saying **`Statements are not allowed in an ambient context.`**

Comment: Aha!  At runtime, `ts-node` doesn't execute all files up front; it only executes the main file and follows `require` and `import` from there.  So assuming your Number extension is in `global.ts`, you have to use either `require("./global");` or `import "./global";` to force `ts-node` to execute the file.  (The latter works even if `global.ts` is not an ES6 module.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Importing the file worked! On a side note, I dug some more and found that when we use the lt/gt **`<`** or **`>`** operators, the `valueOf` function of that object is called. I wanted to ask you about it - for my BST class can I have some constraints such that the generic **`T`** type implements the **`valueOf`** function compulsorily? I am not sure how would I write that.

Comment: You could write something like `class BST<T extends {valueOf(): number}>`, but this approach is not ideal because it may be difficult to convert custom objects to numbers in a way that generates the desired ordering.  I still recommend the custom comparator approach.